# FLEX datagrid and XML list content

Tags: xml, datagrid, flex4

I have the following XML list:

```
<Queries>
    <Query id="1">qq</Query>
    <Query id="2">rr</Query>
    <Query id="3">ss</Query>
</Queries>
```

and I would like to display it in the following datagrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="@{Queries.Query}" editable="true" width="500">
    <mx:columns>
         <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="id" dataField="@id" resizable="false" width="100"/>
         <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Query" dataField="Query"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

The 'id' column is correctly populated but the 'Query' column is empty.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{Queries.Query}" editable="true" width="500">
<mx:columns>
     <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="id" dataField="@id" resizable="false" width="100"/>
     <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Query" dataField="*"/>
</mx:columns>
```

Regards,
Ravish.

Comment: So I believe this question is answered.. :)